# Most Logical Muscle Groups Arrangement and Rest Day?

Tags: rest

I'm in the midst of a heavy lifting routine.

**Here's my current arrangement by day:**

Biceps/Triceps

Calves/Hamstrings

Chest/Abs

Back

Shoulders

Abs

Is there a more optimal arrangement.  And where would you suggest inserting a rest day?

Comment: What is your goal? What exercises, sets, reps are you using to implement this arrangement? How big are you? How's this been going so far? What are some of your lift numbers?

Comment: I dont see any quads in the lineup there.

Comment: Voted to close because of the lack of clarifying edits/comments. As it is, this is a drive-by question.

Comment: Please update your question accordingly and provide what your goals, specific exercises, repetitions, and other supporting information. The more information you can provide, the better an answer you will receive.

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to tell without your training goals, but you state "heavy lifting routine", so I'm going to assume you are trying to build muscle mass.  I would suggest adding squats and leg extensions to your leg day, as these will help release natural testosterone in your body.

I would also suggest isolating pull and push movements on separate days.  Starting with the bigger muscle, you would do something like Chest/Triceps on day one, and then Back/Biceps day 3. Here's an [example](http://www.mensfitness.co.uk/exercise/total_body/3187/pushpull_workout_for_big_muscles.html) of what I mean.

And a whole day for abs? really?  That's just overkill, and if you are looking to get a six-pack, you ain't gonna get it by doing a full day's ab workout.  You'll get much better core results by training your quads and lower back and doing cardio on that day than by dedicating an entire day to abs.